# How to insert fb like into fancybox?

Tags: facebook, fancybox

Is there any way to insert facebook like into pop image of fancybox?

Comment: @CBroe - tryed to add standard like button. I solved with fb like iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fancybox is just another ajax call. you can use HTML5 LIKE buttons

Just trigger the parse function when load complete.

try the simple code below  after the fancybox load , you can run:

```
$("#foo").fancybox({
    'onComplete':function() {
             FB.XFBML.parse(); 
    }
});
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: This does not seem like the correct method anymore (or I am doing something wrong). I can't find anything about this in the docs you linked either.